# EntityFramework core (7th) how to map protected/private properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Looks like the way how private/protected properties mapped to db was changed in EntityFramework core

So what should I do to be able correctly map this class:

```
class Model
{
   protected string _roles {get; set;}
   [NotMapped] 
   public IEnumerables<RoleName> Roles => Parser_rolesToRoleNames(_roles)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand your NotMapped-Property, because it seems to have no name?

To make EF Core map your protected property anyway, in your DbContext in OnModelCreating use the EntityTypeBuilder.Property-Method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .Ignore(m => m.NotMappedProperty)
        .Property(typeof(string), "_roles");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

During batabase creation, the respective column is generated.

To make EF write the values of the private properies to the database, you need to override `SaveChanges`:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                foreach (var pi in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
                {
                    entry.Property(pi.Name).CurrentValue = pi.GetValue(entry.Entity);
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This way all values of your private properties are added to the corresponding change tracker entries and are written to the database on Insert / Update.

Comment: Does this mean I can make a table read-only from EF's point of view just by making the property private and not overriding `SaveChanges`?

Comment: The property name is Roles and it is using the new C# 6 lamba expression property syntax "Properties and indexers can have getters and setters. Expression bodies can be used to write getter-only properties and indexers where the body of the getter is given by the expression body" https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6